# Fraction and simplification

Tags: fractions

> solve: $\frac{1}{x(x-1)} + \frac{1}{x}  = \frac{1}{x-1}$
>
> What are the possible answers ?
>
> (A)  -1   (B) Infinitely Many Solutions (C) No solution (D) 0

The answer from where i've referred this is (B), but when i simplify it  I get (D)

My solution:

$$\frac{1}{x(x-1)} + \frac{1}{x}  = \frac{1}{x-1}$$

$$ \frac{x +x(x-1)}{x(x-1)\cdot x} = \frac{1}{x-1} \text{   (took l.c.m on l.h.s)}$$

$$ \frac{x + (x^2 -x)}{(x^2 - x)\cdot x}= \frac{1}{x-1}$$

$$\frac{x^2}{x^3 - x^2} = \frac{1}{x-1}$$

$$ x^2(x-1) = x^3 - x^2$$

$$ x^3 - x^2 = x^3 - x^2$$

Have I simplified it correctly?

Comment: do you mean $$\frac{1}{x(x-1)}+\frac{1}{x}=\frac{1}{x-1}$$?

Comment: or do you mean $\frac{1}{x}\cdot(x-1)+\frac{1}{x}=\frac{1}{x}-1$? This is what you actually have written, but I suspect that is not what you meant.

Comment: You can see that $x=0$ is not a solution because the term $1/x$ occurs in the equation, but if $x=0$ then $1/x$ does not exist.

Answer (score 4):

You can make it much simpler.

First you have to set the domain of validity: you must have $x\ne 0,1$.

Next, on this domain, remove the denominators multiplying both sides by the l.c.m. of the denominators, and simplify; you get:
$$1+(x-1)=x\iff x=x.$$
Hence any number $x\ne 0,1$ is a solution.

Answer (score 2):

You have got an identity, L.H.S. = R.H.S. which will hold for all values of X in domain of equation. 
This implies Infinite solution as domain of the equation is infinite.
In this case $X ={0,1}$ are not in domain of equation.

Comment: This is incorrect. The domain is not all real numbers.

Comment: @idk i have written explicitly that X in domain of equation, i have not written all real numbers.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply multiply by the LCD, $x(x-1)$ on both sides of the equation.

$$1+(x-1)=x$$

$$x=x$$

Therefore, there are infinitely many solutions for $x$, where $x\ne0,1$.

If $x=0, 1$, then the denominator(s) of the original expression would equal $0$, so the expression would be undefined.

In interval notation, the solutions can be expressed as $(-\infty,0)\cup(0,1)\cup(1,\infty)$.